# pmrep command execution in Informatica cloud

Tags: informatica-cloud

Can anyone tell me is it possible to execute pmrep commands in Informatica Cloud services to import and export workflow object?

pmrep connect -r MY_REP -d MY_DOMAIN -n MY_USER -x MY_PASSWORD
./pmrep objectexport -o workflow -f $FOLDER -n $WORKFLOW -m -s -b -r -u ${EXPORTDIR}/${FOLDER}_${WORKFLOW}.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible in Informatica cloud, you don't have access to the repository it's hosted by Informatica.

You need to use REST API to import and export objects from IICS repository, the document is in the following link.

https://network.informatica.com/docs/DOC-17563

Comment: Thank you for the information on pmrep command . I have found REST API calls such as GET and POST method to export and import objects.

Comment: If you think this answer helped you, please mark it. appreciated